# Move node by tilting device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to move a sphere by tilting my device left and right. The code I have right now is working, except I have to tilt the device up and down - while i state data.acceleration.y --> Y-axis?

Here's my code:

```
 motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
if ([motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable] == YES) {
    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                        withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         float destX, destY;
         float currentX = sphereNode.position.x;
         float currentY = sphereNode.position.y;
         BOOL shouldMove = NO;

         if(data.acceleration.y < -0.25) { // tilting the device to the right
             destX = currentX + (data.acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
             destY = currentY;
             shouldMove = YES;
         } else if (data.acceleration.y > 0.25) { // tilting the device to the left
             destX = currentX + (data.acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed);
             destY = currentY;
             shouldMove = YES;
         }
         if(shouldMove) {
             SKAction *action = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(destX, destY) duration:1];
             [sphereNode runAction:action];
         }
     }];
}
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Y axis is indeed aligned with the top and bottom of the device. You most likely are looking for the x axis of your  CMAccelerometerData data object.

This is all explained in the [Event handling guide for iOS : Motion Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html) documentation.

Maybe having a look at some tutorials (such as [iOS Programming Recipe 19: Using Core Motion to Access Gyro and Accelerometer](http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-19-using-core-motion-to-access-gyro-and-accelerometer/)) could also help you.

Comment: I managed to fix it by changing y to x. Thanks for this documentation!